# Question of remainder on dividing by 7

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Question :

What is the remainder when

$$ 10^{10} + 10^{10^2} +10^{10^3} + \ldots + 10^{10^{100}} $$

is divided by $7$?

Comment: Have you heard about Fermat's little theorem? Euler's theorem?

Comment: Could you please explain ?

Comment: @Anant it's difficult to explain appropriately unless we know which if any of those two theorems sound familiar to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$10^3\equiv-1\pmod7$

For integer $n\ge1,10^n=3\cdot\underbrace{33\cdots33}_{n\text{ digits}}+1$

$\implies10^{10^n}=10(10^3)^{\underbrace{33\cdots33}_{n\text{ digits}}}\equiv10\cdot(-1)^{\underbrace{33\cdots33}_{n\text{ digits}}}\equiv10(-1)\equiv4$ for $n\ge1$

Answer (score 9):

While lab's answer is very elegant, it does rely, in some sense, on luck (as do all elegant answers). Here follows a thorough answer that will let you solve *any* such problem:

First of all, as far as the remainder when divided by $7$ is concerned, there is no difference between $10$ and $3$, so I'm going to work with
$$
3^{10} + 3^{10^2} +3^{10^3} + \cdots + 3^{10^{100}}
$$
The remainders when divided by $7$ of successive powers of $3$ goes like this:
$$
3^1 \mapsto 3\\
3^2 \mapsto 2\\
3^3 \mapsto 6\\
3^4 \mapsto 4\\
3^5 \mapsto 5\\
3^6 \mapsto 1\\
3^7 \mapsto 3
$$
and so on. It turns out that the only thing that is important for the $7$-remainder of a power of $3$ is the remainder of the exponent when divided by $6$ (this is what Fermat's little theorem would tell you directly, so you didn't have to check if you knew that one). So we need to find the $6$-remainder of the different powers of $10$.

Now, as for the $6$-remainder, there is no difference between $10$ and $4$, so I will be focusing on the $6$-remainder of $4^n$. Now, the $6$-remainder of the different powers of $4$ are:
$$
4^1 \mapsto 4\\
4^2 \mapsto 4\\
4^3 \mapsto 4
$$
and we see that the remainder is the same all the way (Euler's theorem would've told us that the only thing that *could* matter was whether the exponent was even or not, and we see here that even that doesn't matter).

So we see that the $7$-remainder of
$$
10^{10} + 10^{10^2} +10^{10^3} + \cdots + 10^{10^{100}}
$$
is the same as the $7$-remainder of
$$
3^{10} + 3^{10^2} +3^{10^3} + \cdots + 3^{10^{100}}
$$
which again is the same as the seven-remainder of
$$
3^{4} + 3^{4^2} +3^{4^3} + \cdots + 3^{4^{100}}
$$
which again is the same as the $7$-remainder of
$$
3^{4} + 3^{4} +3^{4} + \cdots + 3^{4} = 100\cdot 3^4 = 8100
$$
and the remainder of $8100$ when divided by $7$ is $1$.

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thank You!