# Finding remainder when $10^{10}+10^{10^2}+.........+10^{10^{10}}$ is divided by $7$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have found a new problem which asks:

> Find the remainder when $10^{10}+10^{10^2}+.........+10^{10^{10}}$ is divided by $7$.

I am thinking to find the remainder using Fermet's theorem, but I think I am unable to do it.

Please help.

Comment: Hint: $1001 = 7 * 143$.

Comment: Related: [Remainder of $10^{10}+10^{10^2}+10^{10^3}+\cdots+10^{10^{100}}$ when divided by $7$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1334533/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%2410^{10}%2B10^{10^2}%2B...%2B10^{10^{10}}%24&p=1)*)

Comment: Thank you all for your kindness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You can use Fermat's theorem here.

By Fermat's theorem, $10^6\equiv 1 \pmod 7$.

Hence, $10^{6m}\equiv 1 \pmod 7$ for all $m$.

Now, $$10\equiv 4 \pmod 6, 10^2\equiv 40 \equiv 4 \pmod 6$$

By induction, $10^n \equiv 4 \pmod 6$ for all $n$

Thus, $10^n=6m+4$

and $$10^{10n}=10^{6m}\times10^4\equiv 10^4 \pmod 7 \equiv 4 \pmod 7$$

Consequently,

$$10^{10}+10^{10^2}+..........+10^{10^{10}} \equiv 4 \times 10 \pmod 7\equiv 5 \pmod 7$$

So, remainder is $5$.

Comment: You can `\mod` or `\text{mod}` or `\operatorname{mod}` to make the $\text{mod}$ look a little better.

Answer (score 6):

You are right. You should use Fermat's Little Theorem to solve this problem. Fermat's Little Theorem tells us $10^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$, meaning that we can subtract $6$ from each power without affecting the remainder. This means we can just find the remainder of the powers when divided by $6$ and then use those powers.
$$10 \equiv 4 \pmod 6$$
$$10^2 \equiv 4^2 \equiv 16 \equiv 4 \pmod 6$$
$$10^3 \equiv 4^3 \equiv 64 \equiv 4 \pmod 6$$
Hopefully, you see the pattern. All of the powers are equivalent to $4 \pmod 6$. Thus, we can replace each $10^{10^a}$ with $10^4$, giving us a sum of $10\cdot 10^4=10^5$. Now, we need to compute $10^5 \pmod 7$:
$$10^5 \equiv 3^5 \equiv 243 \equiv 5 \pmod 7$$

Answer (score 5):

Observe that $\gcd(10,7)=1$.

Therefore by Euler's theorem: $10^{\phi(7)}\equiv1\pmod7$.

Since $7$ is prime: $\phi(7)=7-1=6$.

Therefore: $10^6\equiv1\pmod7$.

Therefore:

- $10^{10^{1}}\equiv10^{6\cdot1+4}\equiv(\color\red{10^{6}})^{1}\cdot10^{4}\equiv\color\red1^{1}\cdot10^{4}\equiv10000\equiv4\pmod7$
- $10^{10^{2}}\equiv10^{6\cdot16+4}\equiv(\color\red{10^{6}})^{16}\cdot10^{4}\equiv\color\red1^{16}\cdot10^{4}\equiv10000\equiv4\pmod7$
- $10^{10^{3}}\equiv10^{6\cdot166+4}\equiv(\color\red{10^{6}})^{166}\cdot10^{4}\equiv\color\red1^{166}\cdot10^{4}\equiv10000\equiv4\pmod7$
- $\dots$

We can easily prove by induction that $\forall{n\in\mathbb{N}}:10^{10^{n}}\equiv4\pmod7$.

Therefore: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{10}10^{10^{n}}\equiv\sum\limits_{n=1}^{10}4\equiv40\equiv5\pmod7$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ \ \color{#0a0}{a^{\large 9}\equiv\bf 1}\,\Rightarrow\,a^{\large 10^{\Large N}}\!\!\equiv a\ \ $ 
by $\ \ \overbrace{a^{\large\color{#c00}{10^{\Large N}}}\equiv a^{\large \color{#c00}{1+9K}}}
^{\ \ \ \large \color{#c00}{10^{\large N}}\, \equiv\, \color{#c00}{1}           \pmod{\!\color{#c00} 9}}
\!\equiv a(\color{#0a0}{a^{\large 9}})^{\large K}
\!\equiv a (\color{#0a0}{\bf 1})^{\large K}
\!\equiv a$

Comment: Above we used $\!\bmod 9\!:\ 10^n\equiv 1^n\equiv 1\,$ and [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242).  See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/618202/242) for an *idempotent* viewpoint. The OP is case $a = 10^{10}$, so $\!\bmod 7\!:\ a \equiv 3^4\equiv 2^2,\,$ so $\,a^9 \equiv (2^6)^3\equiv 1^3\ \ $

Comment: **Or** $\large \!\bmod 7\!:\! \underbrace{10^{\large \color{#c00}{10}^k}\!\!\equiv (-4)^{\large \color{#c00}4^k}}_{{\rm MOR},\ \color{#c00}{10\ \equiv\ 4}\pmod{\!6}}\!\!\overset{2\:\!\mid\:\! 4^k\!\!}\equiv\, 4^{\large 4^k}\!\!\equiv 4\,$ by $\,\large 4^4\equiv 4\,$ & induction, & MOR = [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) $\ \ $